# Removing CSS "filter: blur" effect - doesn't work

Tags: html, css, blur, css-filters

Does anyone have the idea on how to apply **filter:blur** to "Text A, B, C, etc." lines, but keep *list numbers* (1, 2, 3 - in circles) **unblurred**?

Firstly i tried to do the following (see sample code below):

I added **filter: blur(9px);** to **.meaning** class (which is responsible for BOTH - text and numbers) and I had everything blurred ([see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDkGY.jpg)). Then i tried to *neutralize* blur in list numbers by adding **filter: blur(0)** to **.ol.circle > li:before** class (which, being a ":before" pseudo-class is responsible for list numbers which stand BEFORE the text). No result - numbers stayed blurred.

Then i deleted blur from classes and decided to try to solve the problem through **HTML** part. So i plugged blur *directly* to lines with text:

```
<li style="padding-left:1em;filter: blur(9px)">Text A</li>
```

This again blurred **both** - the text and it's list number. I'm at a loss what to do... :-(

[Code at JSFiddle: clean - no blur](https://jsfiddle.net/nqregf8z/2/)

```
.meaning {
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
width: auto;
text-align: left;
color: #1f2c60;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 600;
filter: blur(9px);
}

ol.circle > li:before {
margin-right: 1em;
margin-left: -2.77em;
content: counter(item);
background: #1f2c60;
border-radius: 100%;
color: white;
width: 1.7em;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
filter: blur(0);
}
```

**SOLVED!** See comment from Brilliand. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/t4nbp38a/) is exactly what i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry guys, maybe i was not clear from the very beginning - the mess is not with "shadow", but with "filter: blur". I need to remove blur from list numbers. I've updated the question (code, screenshot, text itself) for this to be more clear.

Comment: you cannot remove a filter, if you apply filter to an element it will be applied to all its content and you have no way to remove it. You need to target sepcific elements where you want the filter

Comment: Yes, you're right, but when i apply filter to .meaning class, the blur effect affects (for some reason) the ol.circle class as well (which is strange). When i'm trying to disable the filter for ol.circle (via filter: blur(0); command) the blur does NOT disappear. This is the problem i'm trying to solve...

Comment: There is no blur effect. See screenshot: http://screenshot.how/ElL9G3

Comment: Yes, i placed a _clean_ version there. Sample code which adds blur is at the bottom of the post.

Comment: that's what I am trying to explain: you cannot disable a filter on child element by applying blur(0) becaues it's affected by the parent filter. It's like using display:none on a parent element. It will hide all its child element and you cannot use display:block on child to show them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur filter blurs the entire element you apply it to.  It isn't an inherited property, so you can't override it for specific child elements; you need to apply it to only the right things to begin with.

The structure of your `li` elements looks like this:

```
<li style="padding-left:1em">
    ::before
    "Text A"
</li>
```

*(copied from Chrome's dev tools)*

How can you apply styling to only the text part of that structure, without including the ::before?  You... can't.  Not with that structure.  But if you change the structure to this:

```
<li style="padding-left:1em">
    ::before
    <span class="blur-this">Text A</span>
</li>
```

Now you can target just the span for blurring:

```
.blur-this {
    filter: blur(9px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this css:

```
text-shadow: none;
```

Here (The last item) This way the numbers will not have the text-shadow effect. And the text -> Text A... B... will keep on blurred

```css
.meanings_and_examples {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}

ol.circle {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.circle > li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
 }

ol.circle > li:before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-left: -2.77em;
  content: counter(item);
  background: #1f2c60;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  width: 1.7em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block; 
  text-shadow: none;/*add this*/
 }

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.6;  
}

.meaning {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #1f2c60;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.example {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="meanings_and_examples">
<div class="meaning">
<ol class="circle">
  <li style="padding-left:1em">Text A</li>
<div class="example">
   <ul>
      <li>Text B</li>     
   </ul>
</div>
  <li style="padding-left:1em">Text C</li>
<div class="example">
   <ul>
      <li>Text D</li>     
   </ul>
</div>
  <li style="padding-left:1em">Text E</li>              
<div class="example">
   <ul>
      <li>Text F</li>
   </ul>
</div>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but pls. see the comment to the question - the problem is not with the shadow. :-(